Closing a rendezvous channel does not unblock an already blocking send function
First create a rendezvous channel with capacity=0. Then call the send() function of that channel in a concatenated blocking call.
Then call the channel's close() function. channel.send() will block indefinitely without throwing any exceptions.
I understand that I can cancel the send() function by calling channel.cancel(), but why doesn't close work?
Here is the test code:
    @Test
    fun testCloseRendezvousChannel(): Unit = runBlocking {
        // Make sure capacity is zero
        val channel = Channel<Int>(0)

        launch {
            try {
                println("send begin")
                channel.send(0)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("send caught exception: $e")
            } finally {
                println("send over")
            }
        }

        delay(100L)
        channel.close() // do not call channel.cancel()
        println("test over")
        delay(1000L)
    }

output is:
send begin
test over

Expected output send over not got.

Channel.close() is intended to signal that there will be no more elements sent to this Channel, but elements that were already sent but were not received are still available. For a rendezvous channel it means send will suspend even if the channel was closed for sending afterwards.
From documentation on SendChannel.close:

Immediately after invocation of this function, isClosedForSend starts returning true. However, isClosedForReceive on the side of ReceiveChannel starts returning true only after all previously sent elements are received.

Meanwhile cancel not only closes the Channel but also clears the elements:

This function closes the channel and removes all buffered sent elements from it.

So you can add for (n in channel) { println("received: $n") } after channel.close() and it will let the sending coroutine to successfully finish.
